# How to store information about a dynamically created page

Tags: php

So i've been learning PHP fundamentals by following a course on nettuts and I'm having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around how the dynamicly created pages work exactly.

say you have a movie database site (like imdb or similar), you have a view for a movie page and you populate that view with an information (like title, synopsis, pictures etc) from an API. So how exactly would one go about creating for example, most popular movies, most watched movies, watchlist etc functionality. 
What I mean by that is there  exactly and how this information(how many times page is viewed, how many times favorited etc) about a page that doesn't physically exist would be stored.

I realize that this is probably a fairly stupid question, but please enlighten me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to access some web analytic info to build a particular page?

Answer (score 0):

Most Favorited, commented, viewed, discussed..e.t.c

BUT,   Before we delv into the "all" topic, these **comments**, **views**, **discuss** are all datas that are stored in databases, just like articles, comments. 
So, basically, afterwards what you are doing is, making query to databases, to show you a page, based on the another query you give it.

It that didn't make sense, I will try to show an article from database, which has the most comments in it. and  the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT pageID, title,
COUNT(comment) 
FROM comments GROUP by pageID 
ORDER BY COUNT(comment) DESC LIMIT 4"
```

In `PDO` query, the full statement would be:

```
 try{
    $stmt = $this->conn->query(" SELECT pageID, title, 
                                 COUNT(comment) FROM comments 
                                 GROUP by pageID ORDER BY 
                                 COUNT(comment) DESC LIMIT 4");
   }catch (PDOException $e){
           return 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
       }

       foreach($stmt as $row){
           echo "<p class='snotes'><a href='article.php?id=$row[0]'>".$row['title'].'</a></p>';

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **store** the movies in your database(example **MySQL**). **After it** you can access it with queries.